# How to perform a select all on select option(s) without displaying in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have 2 lists generated from my jsp page, before i submit the page to the Controller, i perform a select all using the javascript function below of the 2 lists containing select options. The screen flashes as the lists options are selected/highlighted.

The selected options are then read by the Controller using the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues call.

Is it possible to mark each select option as selected without displaying them as selected to the UI?

```
function selectAll(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    len = element.length;
    if (len != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            element.options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Brendan Crowley You need to do some css tricks like set the highlight, text color as normal. Like below,

```
<style type="text/css">
   option {
     background: #ffffff;
     color: #000000;
     highlight: #C6C4BD;
   }
</style>
```

Choose color based on your form.If you are using jquery you can do it dynamically like

```
$(selector).css({"background":"#ffffff","color":"#000000","highlight":"#C6C4BD"});
```

Hope this helps you.